# android focus error on input in webview

Tags: java, android, eclipse, input, webview

I couldnt do it, it isnt focus to webview's input or textarea

I have click to last input.;

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGG3L.png

It should be same this (android web browser)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFRta.png

what should i do?

MainActivity.js;

```
webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.loadUrl("http://mutlugunluk.com");


        webview.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
        webview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        if (!v.hasFocus()) {
                            v.requestFocus();
                        }
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

activity_main

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Could you please explain the question a bit more.

Comment: I edited. Look to new picture

Comment: What is the problem. Exactly what do you want to do?

Comment: How can I tell i dont know, because i know little english. When i click to input in webview keyboard is openning up on the input. But browser too hasnt this problem.

Comment: Would this help you. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#requestFocus(int, android.graphics.Rect)                          and I'm sorry.

Comment: Or do you mean that you don't want the keyboard to show up when the user tries to search something.

Comment: The soft keyboard on Android covers up text boxes so users can't see what's being typed.

Answer (score 0):

can you try adding this to manifest file in your activity tag   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize", what i understand is the webview is getting the focus but your activity is not getting adjusted to show you the cursor in the textfield.

Comment: Doesnt Work. <activity
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" >
        </activity>

Comment: The soft keyboard on Android covers up text boxes so users can't see what's being typed

Comment: pardon me can you try adjustResize instead of adjustPan

Comment: still doesnt work, can youu add me from skype? lets look together

Comment: do you have a git repository for the same i can look at the code and try it locally first and then we can have a skype if its ok.

Comment: I did some research. But the codes wasnt working. I can not run approximately 4 hours. My skype name : kubi_gs__ i will give you my team viewer info

Answer (score 0):

This is usually done automatically. I recently created a webview and whenever I summoned the keyboard it automatically re-sized the screen size to half the screen making room for the keyboard. So why does this issue occur to you.

Answer (score 0):

It may be android 8.1 bug.
upgrade to 9.0.

In my case this problem is disappeared after upgrade android OS 8.1 to 9.0.

My device is Samsung galaxy tab S4.

In my case:

7.0 ok

8.1 error

9.0 ok ... but I had to div's css layout modifiy fixed to relative. and It is ok.